# Why this message "Local hostname is already in use on this network" for the 4th time?

Tags: terminal, mac, hosts, network

Unlike this question [Local hostname is already in use on this network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246330/local-hostname-is-already-in-use-on-this-network) my computer was already turned on but 'closed' and when I opened it today I received this message:

> This computer's local hostname "(myname)-MacBook-4.local" is already in
>   use on this network. The name has been changed to
>   "(myname)-MacBook-5.local" To change the local hostname, open system
>   preferences and click Sharing, then click "edit" and type the name in
>   the Local Hostname field.

This is the 4 time that I have received this message.

Why?

Should I worry about?

What can I do?

The first time that I received the message was in July and I did what dan said in his answer on the linked question, and it turned out that there was just one IP address, so "this error message was probably an internal bug within the MacOS way to manage its DNS cache." according to dan. Then I got the other 3 messages (at different times) and I did nothing.

However, I did this again today and now the `dns-sd -G v4 (myname)-MacBook-4.local` hangs on the ...STARTING... stage

Why?

If someone could help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you multihoming your computer?  In other words, do you have more than one connection to the *same* network (i.e. wireless and wired) simultaneously?  Is this a home or a work network?  What do you get if you do an `nslookup (myname)-MacBook-4.local`?  Do it again for `Macbook-3` and `-2` as well.  Does it resolve?

Comment: @Allan To your first question, no. I always use wired

Comment: @Allan To your 2nd question is a 'home' I guess // To your 3rd question I got `server:--, address:--` and below this `Non-authoritative answer: Name: -- and Address: -- ` Notice the address are different on both sections // To your 4th question, it's the same, it hangs on the ...STARTING... for `MacBook-3` and `-2`

Comment: @Allan What could be the problem here?

Comment: I’m leaning toward a DNS/DHCP issue. What do you mean by “home I  guess?”  I probably should have worded it better...  do you control the network or does  someone else like a network admin. Let’s get some DHCP info. Issue the command `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep domain ` and post the output

Comment: @Allan What would be that for? what error one would see there?

Comment: It's not an error per se.  It's to tell me what your domain server is set to, the domain search, etc.  It's timing out for a reason and I'm trying to get a lay of the land.